# Use helm to pull container from ACR

Tags: azure, containers, kubernetes-helm

I want use helm chart to pull ACR container. I thing need to provide the ACR image url to helm chart. Please give me the format of helm chart to do that. 
Thanks you.

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps in [Use Azure Container Registry as a Helm repository for your application charts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-helm-repos). And you need to take care of the Azure CLI command [`az acr helm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/helm?view=azure-cli-latest). Configure the ACR name first or use the parameter `--name` in each command.

The steps are simple and show below:

1. create the ACR or use the existing ACR
2. execute the command `az acr helm repo add` to get an authentication token for your Azure container registry that is used by the Helm client
3. fetch the chart through the command `helm fetch`
4. push the chart to ACR
5. update the index available locally through the command `az acr helm repo add`
6. list charts that in your ACR through the command `helm search your_acr_name`

Then you can use the command `helm install your_acr_name/chart_name` to install the chart.

Comment: No, I want to "get" the  container which saved in  Azure Container Registry using Helm. Thank you

Comment: @CườngĐoàn All the things in the Azure Container Registry is the docker image and charts(preview). What do you mean the container?

Comment: sorry i'm bad at english . i want to use helm to pull Repository from ACR

Comment: @CườngĐoàn Actually, you cannot use helm to pull the image directly, you need to create the chart and use the image in it. Helm is used to managing the charts.

Comment: @CườngĐoàn Any update for the question?

Comment: i found the answer. Thanks you

Comment: @CườngĐoàn You just copy the advice of my answer!

Comment: No i found in microsoft page .   https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/33430

Comment: @CườngĐoàn I also explain to you before you find the document. And you also can store the chart in the ACR then use the helm to install.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new helm chart for your application.
I suggest you to go through this document for more information about charts.

I am giving quick info here.
To create a chart from command line use helm create 
It will create a chart with default templates(One deployment, service and one ingress). By default that ingress will be in disabled state.

You can find many files in the chart directory. In that pick values.yaml. You need to give your image details there as shown below.
Part of the values.yaml file is here

image:
  repository: .azurecr.io/
  tag: 
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

After adding these details, You will be able to deploy that image from ACR to AKS.